# How to call `eval` with `with` function?

Tags: r, environment-variables, non-standard-evaluation

Having an `lm` object I need to create a function based on its variables represented as character vector. I have tried to use a combination of `eval` and `expr` to create an `f` function that would be further used in `obj` and `nlm` optimisation of the latter.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- drop_na(airquality)
model <- lm(Ozone~. - Temp, data = df, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
base_vars <- all.vars(formula(model)[-2])
k <- length(base_vars)

f <- function(base_df, x, y, parms) {
  with(base_df, parms[1] + 
         eval(expr(paste(paste(paste0('parms[', 2:(k+1), ']'), base_vars, sep = '*'), collapse = '+'))) + 
         log(parms[k+2] * (x - parms[k+3] ^ 2)))
}
obj <- function(parms, y, x) mean((residuals(model) - f(df, x, y, parms))^2) 
fit <- with(data, nlm(obj, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), y = e, x = x))
```

But calling `f(model$x, df$Temp, model$y, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))` results in the following error:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one 
4.
eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) 
3.
with.default(base_df, parms[1] + eval(expr(paste(paste(paste0("parms[", 
    2:(k + 1), "]"), base_vars, sep = "*"), collapse = "+"))) + 
    log(parms[k + 2] * (x - parms[k + 3]^2))) 
2.
with(base_df, parms[1] + eval(expr(paste(paste(paste0("parms[", 
    2:(k + 1), "]"), base_vars, sep = "*"), collapse = "+"))) + 
    log(parms[k + 2] * (x - parms[k + 3]^2))) 
1.
f(model$x, df$Temp, model$y, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I believe there might be a conflict between `eval` environment and environment implied by `with` function, but can't figure out why. Any ideas how can I create custom function `f` for variable models?

Expected output for the `f(model$x, df$Temp, model$y, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))` would be:

```
with(base_df, parms[1]+parms[2]*Solar.R+parms[3]*Wind+parms[4]*Temp+parms[5]*Month+
              parms[6]*Day+log(parms[7] * (Temp - parms[8] ^ 2)))
```

but for a different model it could be something like:

```
with(base_df, 
     parms[1]+parms[2]*var1+parms[3]*var2+log(parms[4]*(var3-parms[5]^2)))
```

so the number of variables and parameters is different with every call.

Comment: Can you describe in words what exactly you want this `f` function to do? There may be a much better way than bothering with `eval`

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your function is supposed to return there. A formula object? How should the formula look like?

Comment: The f function should create a function that has a linear part (using `model` variables) and non-linear part `log(A * (x-B))`. That function is needed to facilitate `obj` function that is supposed to be used in `nlm` optimisation. (I have edited the code accordingly)

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you write down the formula for the linear part? I suspect I can provide an easy solution but your convoluted code attempt does not provide a clear requirement.

Comment: I have updated with expected output. Please see the post above.

Answer (score 5):

R supports computing on the language, but it should not be your first option. If you do it, it should never involve text processing of code. You don't have a case here where you need to compute on the language. I have no idea how you thought your attempt would work but I don't know the `expr` function and I refuse to install package tidyverse and its ginormous dependency tree.

Also, you generally should avoid `with` outside of interactive use. But `with` is not the problem here.

Here is how I would do this:

```
df <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]
model <- lm(Ozone~. - Temp, data = df)

f <- function(base_df, x, parms) {

  m <- model.matrix(model, data = base_df)
  k <- ncol(m)
  stopifnot(length(parms) == (k + 2L))
  #I use exp(parms[k+1]) to ensure a positive value within the log
  m %*% parms[seq_len(k)] + log(exp(parms[k + 1L]) * (x - parms[k + 2L] ^ 2))

}

obj <- function(parms, y, x, base_df) mean((residuals(model) - f(base_df, x, parms))^2) 

#some x:
x <- rpois(nrow(df), 10)

fit <- nlm(obj, c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = x, base_df = df)
#works
```

You don't seem to use `y` and thus I removed it from the code.

Note how I create the design matrix for the linear part (using `model.matrix`) and use matrix multiplication with the parameters. You also need to ensure that `log` doesn't return `Inf`/`-Inf`/`NaN`.

Comment: `expr()` is from *rlang*, which doesn't have dependencies, it is like `quote()` except it supports quasi quotation.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Roland gave a good answer covering your actual problem. I am isolating what I think you were specifically asking based on the question Title, with no comment on whether it is a good idea or not. It probably isn't in this use case.

But what you were looking for more than likely is `eval_tidy()` from `rlang`. I left the `::` function notation in just so its obvious what package is being used here.

Note I fixed a couple things that seemed to be errors in the code. I am also using all ones instead of zeros to test in `parms` due to the log.

```r
library(rlang)
library(tidyr)

# dropped y since it was an unused argument
f <- function(base_df, x, parms) {
  # set an expression to evaluate using parse_expr()
  .f <- rlang::parse_expr(paste(paste(paste0('parms[', 2:(k+1), ']'),
                                      base_vars, sep = '*'), collapse = '+'))

  # use eval_tidy() with the data mask  
  y_part1 <- rlang::eval_tidy(.f, data = base_df)
  y_part2 <- log(parms[k + 2] * (x - parms[k + 3] ^ 2))

  parms[1] + y_part1 + y_part2
}

# using your code
df <- tidyr::drop_na(airquality)
model <- lm(Ozone~. - Temp, data = df, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
base_vars <- all.vars(formula(model)[-2])
k <- length(base_vars)

# changed to all ones, I think this is what you wanted for length
parms <- rep(1, k + 3)

method_1 <- f(df, df$Temp, parms)

method_2 <- with(df, parms[1]+parms[2]*Solar.R+parms[3]*Wind+parms[4]*Temp+parms[5]*Month+
                   parms[6]*Day+log(parms[7] * (Temp - parms[8] ^ 2)))


all.equal(method_1, method_2)
# [1] TRUE
```